# Resize ListBox height declaration for win64

Tags: vba, excel

I found a piece of code that enables my User form list boxes to resize in height based on the number of inputs, but the declaration is for win32 and i do not know how to change it to win 64 correctly, please help. Here it is:

```
Option Explicit
Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" _
Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, _
ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Any) As Long

Private Const LB_GETITEMHEIGHT = &H1A1


Public Function AutoSizeLBHeight(LB As Object) As Boolean
If Not TypeOf LB Is ListBox Then Exit Function
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Dim lItemHeight As Long
Dim lRet As Long
Dim lItems As Long
Dim sngTwips As Single
Dim sngLBHeight As Single
If LB.ListCount = 0 Then
    LB.Height = 125
    AutoSizeLBHeight = True
Else
    lItems = LB.ListCount
    lItemHeight = SendMessage(LB.hwnd, LB_GETITEMHEIGHT, 0&, 0&)
    If lItemHeight > 0 Then
        sngTwips = lItemHeight * Screen.TwipsPerPixelY
        sngLBHeight = (sngTwips * lItems) + 125
        LB.Height = sngLBHeight
        AutoSizeLBHeight = True
    End If
End If
ErrHandler:
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/apideclarations.asp has everything you need.

> The SendMessage API is a good example because it uses both types:

```
32-bit:
Public Declare Function SendMessageA Lib "user32" ( _
    ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, _
    ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long

64 bit:
Public Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessageA Lib "user32" ( _
    ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal wMsg As Long, _
    ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As LongPtr
```

> The first argument -hWnd- is a window handle, which is an address in memory. The return value is a pointer to a function, which is also an address in memory. Both of these must be declared LongPtr in 64-bit VBA. The arguments wMsg and wParam are used to pass data, so they can be Long in both 32-bit and 64-bit.

But you are aware that you only need this for 64bit-Excel, not for 64bit-Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Using Compiler Directives will allow the code to run properly on either platform.

```
#If Win64 Then

Private Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal wMsg As Long, _
                                                           ByVal wParam As LongPtr, lParam As Any) As LongPtr
#ElseIf Win32 Then

Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA"  (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, _
                                                   ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
#End If
```